# .htaccess redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my site `www.freerankstat.com` has old url parameter like `www.freerankstat.com/facebook.com` and new parameter `www.freerankstat.com/www/facebook.com`

I try to use .htaccess file but google webmaster showing 80K+ error for not available..

I am using following code in .htaccess file..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.freerankstat.com/www/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

I anticipate your help..

regards
Keshab

Comment: You should know that google webmaster takes a lot of time before update, especialy if it have to update 80K+ links

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a condition to prevent rewrite looping

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.freerankstat.com/www/$1 [R=301,NC]
```